# Linguistic name for "general action verbs" and "specific action verbs"

Tags: verbs

Is there a linguistic or academical name for those verbs which express a general action compared to those which express a specific action?

Examples:

- *do*, *make* (general) vs. *perform*, *build* (specific)
- *have* (general) vs. *carry* (specific)
- *get* (general) vs. *achieve*, *obtain* (specific)
- *use* (general) vs. *apply* (specific)
- *say* (general) vs. *whisper*, *explain*, *confess* (specific)

I found [this](http://ourenglishclass.net/class-notes/writing/the-writing-process/craft/specific-verbs/), but *boring verbs* vs. *specifical verbs* does not sound very academical to me...

Comment: General vs. specific is [*hyponymy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy). *Say* is a hypernym of *whisper*, for example. However, as is always the case with all these -nyms — hypernyms, hyponyms, synonyms, antonyms... —, they only really exist in context. For example, *carry* is not necessarily more specific than *have*. "I have a Colt in my left pocket" is way more specific than "I carry a concealed weapon". And *do* has so many meanings that it's a hypernym, a hyponym, and an antonym of itself. Likewise with *get*. So I'm not really sure what you're after.

Comment: I recently ran across the term [**light verb**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_verb), which appears to answer your need. I didn't see anything in the literature to suggest that it's particularly useful to me, so I'm not in a position to advance this as an Answer; but it's apparently of some importance to linguists, particularly computational linguists.

Answer (score 1):

The main division is between lexical verbs, primary verbs and modal verbs. *Do* and *have* are primary verbs, that is, they can function both as auxiliary and main verbs. All the others in your list are lexical verbs. Lexical verbs can be sub-divided into several further categories, but I know of no system that specifically divides verbs in the way you suggest.

However, for words nouns and verbs a structure of hyponymy is sometimes present. This is a hierarchy in which one general word covers several specific ones. A poodle is a kind of dog, which is a kind of animal, which is a kind of creature. In your list, it might be possible to say that *explain* was a hyponym of *say*, but I don’t think the system holds up particularly well for the examples you have given.

Comment: Well, I listed a group of verbs which, to me, seemed to exemplify what I meant in the question. I never meant them to be the most important part of my question. I was just wondering if there are names for these verbs better than _general action verbs_ and _specifical action verbs_, which are the names I gave in the title of the question. I suppose I could use these names, then.